# Triggered a breakpoint (Destructor) with class template type is a version of itself?

Tags: c++, class, templates, destructor

With a class like this:

```
template <class Type>
class test {
    Type* ptr;
public:
    test() {
        ptr = new Type;
    }
    test(int x) {
        ptr = new int;
        *ptr = x;
    }
    test(const test<Type>& other) {
        ptr = new Type;
        *ptr = *other.ptr;
    }
    ~test() {
        delete ptr;
        cout << "Deleted " << typeid(test<Type>).name() << endl;
    }

    Type& getptr () {
        return *ptr;
    }
};
```

And use it:

```
int main() {
    test<int> a = 5;     // This seems to be fine
    test<int> c = a;     // This seems to be fine
    test<test<int>> b;
    b.getptr() = a;      // This seems fine to me

    cout << b.getptr().getptr() << endl;  // This worked (Printed 5)

    return 0;
}
```

Then a breakpoint is triggered at the line

```
delete ptr;
```

When I delete the line (Cause I know it causing the error but I dont know why)

```
 b.getptr() = a;
```

or change it to

```
 b.getptr().getptr() = 5;
```

everything work.



So why does a breakpoint is triggered when I use

```
 b.getptr() = a;
```

but

```
test<int> c = a;
b.getptr().getptr() = 5;
```

both worked? Isn't they're the same as "b.getptr()" return a reference to *(b.ptr) which is the same to the line above and they're all have the same type "test"? (I tested this too)

```
cout << typeid(b.getptr()).name() << endl; // Print "class test<int>"
```

And also, with

```
b.getptr() = a;
```

it's still print the correct output.
Can someone explain what am I doing wrong or missing? I've tried searching for answer myself but I can't still neither understand what's wrong nor found a way to fix it.
Thank you.

Sorry for my terrible English, also because of that I can't find a better way to describe my question better in the title.

Comment: I suppose that, instead of `test(int x) { ptr = new int; *ptr = x; }`, your intention was `test(Type x) { ptr = new Type; *ptr = x; }`

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [rule of 5/3/0](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius It's does, "test(const test<Type>& other)" isn't this is a copy constructor? Also "test<int> c = a; " doesn't cause any crash as I mentioned above (When I delete the line that I suspected everything worked normally)

Comment: @G.M. Thanks, it's solved everything

Comment: @TríTrầnMinh - yes: you've done a copy constructor; but you need also an explicit `operator=(test<Type> const &)`; when you write `b.getptr() = a; ` isn't the copy constructor but the `operator=()` that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the instruction

```
b.getptr() = a;
```

both `a` and `b` contain a pointer to the same allocated value.

This is because `b.getptr()` return a reference to the managed `(*ptr)`, that is a `test<int>`, and copying in it `a` you copy the `ptr` in `a` in `(*ptr).ptr`.

So, at the end of `main()`, you delete two times the same allocated memory: crash!

Well... the crash isn't guaranteed (you have an undefined behavior) but often you have a crash. (thanks to Algirdas Preidžius that pointed it)

When you directly manage allocated memory, you need copy constructors and you need to define an `operator=()` to avoid this sort of problem.
Starting from C++11, you also need a move constructor and an `operator=()` that receive a right reference.

Comment: "_you delete two times the same allocated memory: crash_" Technically, the action of double-delete is undefined behavior. You only get a crash if you are "lucky".

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius - I'm often "lucky" :( . But you're right; answer improved.